# Neo4j Cypher - Results need to be filtered based on each node in the path

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

My cypher query is

```
MATCH path = (n:Person {Name:'John'})-[:OutNode|InNode*]-()-[:EndNode]->(endNode) 
WITH path,[i in nodes(path) where 'InNode' in labels(i)] as InNodes 
WHERE ALL  (i IN InNodes WHERE i.Status in ['Active','InActive'] 
AND NOT i.oStatus in ['Suspended','Closed']  )  
RETURN path
```

Here I am validating each InNode in the path with Status and oStatus validation. It is working fine till this validation. Now I want to check whether this InNode have another Out Relationship with property check. If I add below condition in above code then I am getting error.

```
AND exists {MATCH (i) - [:OutNode2] -> (o)  
WHERE NOT o.name in ['SampleVal1','SampleVal2'] }
```

Is there any alternative to achieve this validation ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The variable InNodes is a list of nodes (InNode) in the path. Thus you need to do the match per node.  Use UNWIND and it works like a for loop. I guess this query will work since you did not give us sample data to work on. Please try it and let me know if it works or not.

```
MATCH path = (n:Person {Name:'John'})-[:OutNode|InNode*]-()-[:EndNode]->(endNode) 
WITH path,[i in nodes(path) where 'InNode' in labels(i)] as InNodes 
WHERE ALL  (i IN InNodes WHERE i.Status in ['Active','InActive'] 
AND NOT i.oStatus in ['Suspended','Closed']  )  
WITH path, InNodes
UNWIND InNodes as i
MATCH (i)-[:OutNode2]->(o) WHERE NOT o.name in ['SampleVal1','SampleVal2']
RETURN path
```